# Resolvent also self-adjoint operator

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

If I have a self-adjoint operator $U : \operatorname{dom}(U) \subset H \rightarrow H$ and $\lambda \in \rho(U)$, then I assume assume that it is correct that the operator $(U - \lambda I)^{-1} \in L(H)$ is also self-adjoint?(for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R})

I mean, if $U$ would have been bounded, then I guess this would have been clear, as $(U- \lambda I)$ would have been self-adjoint and $(T^*)^{-1}= (T^{-1})^*$ holds, but in this more general setting, I am not so sure anymore.

Edit: So one question, if I have a self-adjoint operator $T$ (unbounded) and I have $((T-\lambda)^{-1})^{*}$ where $\lambda \in \rho(T)$, then it is clear that $(T-\overline{\lambda})^{-1}$ is also a bounded operator. So if I now show that $(f,g) \in G(((T-\lambda)^*)^{-1}) \Leftrightarrow  (g,f) \in G((T-\lambda)^*) \text{ and }\forall (h,k) \in G((T-\lambda)): \langle k,g \rangle = \langle h,f \rangle  \Leftrightarrow (f,g) \in G(((T-\lambda)^{-1})^{*}) \text{ and }  \forall (k,h) \in G((T-\lambda)^{-1}) : \langle k,g \rangle  = \langle h,f\rangle$, then this is the full proof?

Comment: If $U$ is selfadjoint then $(U-\lambda I)^{-1}$ has adjoint $(U-\overline{\lambda}I)^{-1}$. So the resolvent is normal, but is not selfadjoint unless $\lambda$ is real. And there may not be any real $\lambda$ in the resolvent if $U$ is unbounded.

Comment: @T.A.E. yes, I forgot that. Is it difficult to show this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adjoints of closed densely-defined linear operators on a Hilbert space $X$ are nice, once you get used to working in the graph space. In fact, the proofs are easier using these techniques for general closed densely-defined operators than the special-case proofs offered for the bounded case. John von Neumann introduced this way of working with densely-defined linear operators on a Hilbert space $X$. I'll explain his approach.

**A Graph:** The first thing to observe is that a subspace $\mathcal{M}\subseteq X\times X$ is the graph $\mathcal{G}(L)=\{ \langle x, Lx\rangle : x\in\mathcal{D}(L)\}$ of a linear operator $L : \mathcal{D}(L)\subseteq X\rightarrow X$ iff $\langle 0,y\rangle \in \mathcal{M}$ implies $y=0$. And $L$ is a closed linear operator iff its graph is a closed in the product space $X\times X$. If the subspace $\mathcal{M}$ is a graph, then the domain of $L$ becomes the set of all first coordinates in the subspace $\mathcal{M}$. It is easy to show that this unique correspondence between $x \in \mathcal{D}(L)$ and the second coordinate is linear because $\mathcal{M}$ is linear.

**Closable:** A linear operator $L : \mathcal{D}(L)\subseteq X\rightarrow X$ is closable iff the closure $\mathcal{G}(L)^{c}$ in $X\times X$ of its graph $\mathcal{G}(L)$ is a graph. Equivalently, if $\{ x_{n} \}\subseteq \mathcal{D}(L)$ converges to $0$ and $\{ Ax_{n} \}$ converges to some $y$, then $y=0$. That's the condition for a linear operator to have a closed extension, and is equivalent to the requirement that the closure of the graph of $L$ be the graph of a linear operator.

**Inverses:** If $L$ is a linear operator, then $L^{-1}$ exists iff the transpose of the graph of $L$ is a graph. Using the transpose map $\tau\langle x,y\rangle = \langle y,x\rangle$,
$$
                    \tau \mathcal{G}(L)=\mathcal{G}(L^{-1}),
$$
provided both exist. Notice that if $L^{-1}$ exists, then $L^{-1}$ is closed iff $L$ is closed because $\tau$ is a unitary map on $X\times X$ with $\tau^{2}=I$.

**Adjoints:** The real power of using graphs comes in defining the adjoint. If $L$ is a closed densely-defined linear operator, then $L$ has a closed densely-defined adjoint $L^{\star}$ whose graph is
$$
                      \mathcal{G}(L^{\star})=J[\mathcal{G}(L)^{\perp}],
$$
where the orthogonal complement is taken in $X\times X$ and $J$ is the unitary symplectic transpose
$$
              J\langle x, y\rangle = \langle y, -x\rangle.
$$
Notice that $J^{2}=-I$. Because $\tau$ and $J$ are unitary, they commute with the action of taking orthogonal complement. So you may also write
$$
        \mathcal{G}(L^{\star})=J[\mathcal{G}(L)^{\perp}]=[J\mathcal{G}(L)]^{\perp}.
$$
Of course the transpose operator $\tau$ also commutes with the action of taking the orthogonal complement.

**Commutativity:** Also note that $\tau J = - J\tau$, which means $\tau J\mathcal{M}=J\tau\mathcal{M}$ for subspaces $\mathcal{M}$ of $X\times X$. So, when you are considering the action of $J$, $\tau$ and $\perp$ on subspaces $\mathcal{M}\subseteq X\times X$, you can freely interchange these operations. That makes life very simple.

**Your Example:** Suppose that $L$ is a closed densely defined linear operator with a densely-defined inverse $L^{-1}$. Automatically $L^{-1}$ is closed because $L$ is closed (their graphs are transposes of each other.) That means that $L^{-1}$ will have a closed densely-defined adjoint $(L^{-1})^{\star}$. As you might guess, $(L^{-1})^{\star}=(L^{\star})^{-1}$.

To show $(L^{-1})^{\star}=(L^{\star})^{-1}$: First, you must show that $L^{\star}$ has an inverse, which comes down to showing $\tau\mathcal{G}(L^{\star})$ is a graph:
$$
    \tau\mathcal{G}(L^{\star})=\tau[J\mathcal{G}(L)^{\perp}]=
           [J\tau\mathcal{G}(L)]^{\perp}=
             [J\mathcal{G}(L^{-1})]^{\perp}=\mathcal{G}((L^{-1})^{\star}).
$$
Obviously the subspace on the far right is a graph. So $L^{\star}$ has an inverse and $(L^{\star})^{-1}=(L^{-1})^{\star}$. This proves the following:

> **Lemma:** Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $L$ a densely-defined closed linear operator on $H$. If $L$ has a densely-defined inverse $L^{-1}$, then $L^{\star}$ has a densely-defined inverse, and $(L^{\star})^{-1}=(L^{-1})^{\star}$.

Note: If $L^{-1}$ is defined everywhere then it is bounded by the closed graph theorem. In that case $(L^{\star})^{-1}$ is also defined everywhere and is bounded because of the graph equation stated in the lemma. This is the case in your problem for $L=U-\lambda I$ because resolvents are, by definition, defined everywhere and are bounded.

**Added in Response to your Addition:** Another big fact. If $A$ is closed and densely-defined then $A^{\star\star}=A$. This is because $(\mathcal{M}^{\perp})^{\perp}=\mathcal{M}$ for a closed subspace of a Hilbert space such as $H\times H$. This extends the previous lemma.

> **Lemma:** Let $L$ be a closed densely-defined linear operator on a Hilbert space $H$ with adjoint $L^{\star}$. Then $L^{-1}$ exists as a densely-defined linear operator iff $(L^{\star})^{-1}$ exists as a densely-defined linear operator and, in either case, $(L^{-1})^{\star}=(L^{\star})^{-1}$.

**Proof:** I showed you that if $L$ has a densely-defined inverse, then $L^{\star}$ has a densely defined inverse and $(L^{-1})^{\star}=(L^{\star})^{-1}$. Conversely, if $L^{\star}$ has a densely-defined inverse, then $(L^{\star})^{\star}=L$ has a densely-defined inverse and $((L^{\star})^{-1})^{\star}=L^{-1} \implies (L^{\star})^{-1}=(L^{-1})^{\star}$. $\;\;\Box$

As a corollary: If $L$ is a closed densely-defined linear operator on a Hilbert space, then $L-\lambda I$ has a densely-defined inverse iff $L^{\star}-\overline{\lambda}I$ has a densely-defined inverse and, in either case,
$$
                  ((L-\lambda I)^{-1})^{\star}=(L^{\star}-\overline{\lambda}I)^{-1}.
$$
In particular, $\lambda \in\rho(L)$ iff $\overline{\lambda}\in\rho(L^{\star})$ and the resolvents satisfy $R_{L}(\lambda)^{\star}=R_{L^{\star}}(\overline{\lambda})$. This last equation holds very generally in the sense that one exists iff the other does and, in that case, the two always equal. So, if $L=L^{\star}$ then $\lambda\in\rho(L)$ iff $\overline{\lambda}\in\rho(L)$ and, in that case, $R_{L}(\lambda)^{\star}=R_{L}(\overline{\lambda})$.

Comment: ah yes, i read about it. these things are also called linear relations, right?

Comment: I added a question about the proof to my initial question, cause it became to long for a comment. somehow I feel surprised about the shortness of this proof and since I am not very familiar with this concept, I wanted to be sure that I understood this.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot switching elements in one place.Well, I think what I do is not so different from what you do, but I just wanted to stick to the elements. So if I have an inverse, I change components and if I have an adjoint, I look at $\langle k,f \rangle - \langle g,h \rangle = 0$. So $T^{-1}:=\{(f,g); (g,f) \in T\}$ and $T^*:=\{(f,g) ; (k,h) \in T: \langle h,f \rangle = \langle g,k \rangle\}$. Does it now make sense to you?

Comment: I hope to understand this more conceptually that way, but if it is difficult for you to follow my arguments, then we can also leave it there.

Comment: @TobiasHurth : The reason I don't like your definition of $T^{\star}$ is that it suggests the set of elements is a graph already. If $T$ is closed and densely-defined, then your definition is okay, but it hides those details of closed and densely-defined. A more practical definition would start with the domain consisting of all $y$ for which there exists $z$ such that $(Tx,y)=(x,z)$ for all $x\in\mathcal{D}(T)$. Equivalently, there exists a constant $m$ such that $|(Tx,y)|\le m\|x\|$ for all $x\in\mathcal{D}(T)$. For a given $y$, such $z$ is unique because $\mathcal{D}(T)$ is dense.

Comment: but in the example, I am considering, we have that $T$ is closed and densely-defined, so I see your point, but do you think that my argument is alright in that case?

Comment: @TobiasHurth : Yes, your argument is sound. Side issue: the second definition of domain as the set of $y$ such that $|(Tx,y)|\le m\|x\|$, $x\in\mathcal{D}(T)$ is a very useful alternative that deals with $y$ without the second element $z$, and this is an advantage of an element approach that uses Riesz representation.

Comment: ah, thank you again. this helped quite a lot.

Comment: As a suggestion: You may add Hellinger Toeplitz seen from the graph perspective to your list. Proving boundedness may be skipped when knowing symmetry and domain being all. That may be used wonderfully in GNS construction. *(You showed me this a year ago! :))*

Comment: By the way I was always wondering wether one can work with graphs too when showing the relation between range and kernel w.r.t. to adjoints. Is that possible?

Comment: However, if I'm not mistaken, the graph perspective doesn't work on sums and products of operators. That lies in the fact that they don't behave well with sets as for example $A+A\neq 2A$.